# Lockerservice Swallowing Method Return Value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, locker-service

I am not able to use certain methods of the `LocalizationService`. The results of the `parseDateTime` and `parseDateTimeUTC` methods are being swallowed by the LockerService for some reason. Eg:

```
var d = "2015-10-09";
//Should return "Thu Oct 08 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
console.log($A.localizationService.parseDateTimeUTC(d,'yyyy-MM-dd'));
//Actual :{}
```

Is anyone aware of a way around this or of an upcoming fix? This should work given that it's available in the reference app.

Comment: No [Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=localizationService).

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean it's not an issue - just that it's not known yet...

Comment: Added a bug fo us to review. Thank for bringing this up.

Comment: Awesome thanks!! (Will mean I can remove my dependency on moment.js - and offload that dependency to you ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue where LockerService was not handling the native `Date` object properly has been fixed in a recent patch. Can you confirm this is now fixed?

Comment: A very long weekend... :) - but yes, it's been successfully fixed. I've been able to remove all use of moment.js in my Datepicker. Thanks!